# Is this statement true for two sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $T$ and $S$ be two sets.

If for all elements $(x, y) \in T$ we also have $(x, y) \in S$, then it is not necessarily true that for all elements $(x, y) \in S$ we have $(x, y) \in T$.

Would this be correct?

Thank you.

Comment: what you are describing sounds like $T \subseteq S$. So No, this does not imply $S \subseteq T$.

Comment: Of course... an example of where it is true is when $T=S=\{(a,b)\}$ and an example of where it is not true is when $T=\{(a,b)\}$ and $S=\{(a,b),(c,d)\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example: $T=\{(0,0)\}$ and $S=\{(0,0),(123,456)\}$.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to why this is correct. Does not the Op ask if it would be true for all elements, not just some? Why then is a specific example involving only a few elements considered an answer?
Not trying to criticize just curious.

Comment: @user400188: Because this example is a witness that the claim in the question is true, which is equivalent to the existence of two sets $S,T$ for which it is not true that for all elements $(x,y)∈S$ we have $(x,y)∈T$.

Comment: Ah, I believe I read the question wrong. I saw "it is not necessarily true" as "is it not necessarily true" mistaking the it as an is. Funny how one word can negate the meaning in the English language.